# Slow query response time - simple friends of friends cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using NEO4j 3.5 to store and query relationships between people. I have nodes with the label "User" and relationships with the label of "Friends". I am able to get the friends of friends, but the query is taking too long. It currently returns in 4sec to 6sec. This is not a high transactional neo4j database and the server has plenty of CPU and memory available. The loads on the server are under 3 and there are 8 cores. This is running on an AWS EC2 instance. There are roughly 250,000 nodes in the database and the total database size is under 750mb.

Here is the query that I am currently using:

```
MATCH (user:User {user_id:1145})-[:FRIENDS*3]->(fof:User)
WHERE NOT (user:User)-[:FRIENDS]->(fof:User)
RETURN count(distinct fof.user_id)
```

This cypher query returns a count of 69,704, which is correct.

What optimizations can be made either to the cypher query or the NEO4j database  engine to return the results faster?

**Execution Plan**

```
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows   | DB Hits | Cache H/M | Identifiers                 | Ordered by       | Other                                      |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |              0 |      1 |       0 |       0/0 | count(distinct fof.user_id) |                  | 0.0                                        |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |              0 |      1 |  326421 |       0/0 | count(distinct fof.user_id) |                  | 0.0                                        |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |              0 | 256717 |       0 |       0/0 | anon[33], fof, user         | user.user_id ASC | 0.0                                        |
| |\                    +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(Into)       |              0 |      0 | 8006149 |       0/0 |   REL80, fof, user          |                  | 0.0; (user)-[  REL80:FRIENDS]->(fof)       |
| | |                   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter             |              1 | 260120 |  520240 |       0/0 | fof, user                   |                  | 0.0; fof:User                              |
| | |                   +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| | +Argument           |              1 | 260120 |       0 |       0/0 | fof, user                   |                  | 0.0                                        |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 | 260120 |  260120 |       0/0 | anon[33], fof, user         | user.user_id ASC | 0.0; fof:User                              |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |              0 | 260120 |  267999 |       0/0 | anon[33], fof, user         | user.user_id ASC | 0.0; (user)-[anon[33]:FRIENDS*3..3]->(fof) |
| |                     +----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek        |              1 |      1 |       3 |       0/0 | user                        | user.user_id ASC | 0.0; :User(user_id)                        |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Keep in mind also that :FRIENDS*3 is not friends-of-friends, but friends-of-friends-of-friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `WHERE` clause contains a pattern that requires additional DB hits per `fof`. You can avoid those DB hits by keeping in memory a list of all the immediate friends of `user`, and changing your `WHERE` clause so that it just searches in the list. (According to your profile data, this could save 8006149+520240, or over 8.5 million DB hits -- which is the majority of the hits for your whole query.)
2. In your query, if the same `fof` node is matched multiple times, the same `WHERE` test will be performed every time. You can avoid that by filtering out duplicate `fof` nodes *before* doing the `WHERE` test. This also means you no longer need to remove duplicates later.

For example:

```
MATCH (user:User {user_id:1145})-[:FRIENDS]->(f:User)
WITH user, COLLECT(f) AS friends
MATCH (user)-[:FRIENDS*3]->(fof:User)
WITH DISTINCT friends, fof
WHERE NOT fof IN friends
RETURN COUNT(fof)
```